# can't find crate for `std` while cross-compiling Rust project for ARM

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

I have followed the [steps in the instructions](https://github.com/Ogeon/rust-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/MANUAL.md) very carefully, but when I try to cross compile my Cargo project using [its script](https://github.com/Ogeon/rust-on-raspberry-pi/blob/master/cross32), 
I get an error while compiling the dependencies for my project:

```
Compiling libc v0.2.4                                                                                                                   
/root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a/libc-0.2.4/src/lib.rs:1:1: 1:1 error: can't find crate for `std` [E0463]             
/root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-88ac128001ac3a9a/libc-0.2.4/src/lib.rs:1 // Copyright 2012-2015 The Rust Project Developers. See the C
OPYRIGHT                                                                                                                                   
                                                                              ^                                                            
error: aborting due to previous error                                                                                                      
Could not compile `libc`.
```

Comment: I won't be very helpful, but I'd advise to ask the instruction author. Create an issue on github.

Comment: This was [cross-posted to Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/40ypxk/cant_find_crate_while_crosscompiling_rust_project/).